# Duplicate targets are being overridden by Sphinx and hyperlink targets cannot be referenced

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

So I either just have no understanding of how links are supposed to work in Sphinx (despite reading all the documentation I can find) or something very funky is going on.

Firstly, as I understand it, targets must be globally unique in a project so that they can be referenced from anywhere. However, I am able to create explicit targets on two different pages with the same label and I do not get any warnings or errors when building the docs. Instead, one of the targets just seems to take precedence over the other.

Contents of `page-1.rst`

```
.. _abc:

Some content...

Now here's a :ref:`reference to content <abc>`.
```

Contents of `page-2.rst`

```
.. _abc:

Some different content...
```

Building this produces no warnings or errors. The reference links to the target on `page-1.rst`. Based on my understanding, I'd expect this to warn me about duplicate targets defined across the project. The same thing happens if I move the target (but keep the reference) from `page-1.rst` to, say, `page-3.rst`. No warnings, but in this case `page-3.rst` takes precedence for some reason. Why am I not getting warned about these duplicate targets? I have pretty vanilla configuration, and I've disabled any extensions when checking this functionality.

Additionally, I've found that external link targets don't seem to work with the `ref` role, but I don't really understand why, and I can't find any information about this. The use case is wanting to reference the same external URL in two separate pages. I understand there is some additional configuration I can do set up a base url and use that in multiple places, but this seems more complicated than what I'm looking for. Basically, why can't I do something like this:

Contents of `page-1.rst`

```
.. _abc: https://example.com
```

Contents of `page-2.rst`

```
You really ought to visit :ref:`this place <abc>`.
```

Building this results in

```
WARNING: undefined label: abc
```

Ultimately, these are just things that feel like they go against my intuition based on what I've learned, but I'm starting to wonder if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you run `make clean` after adding the duplicate target? Sphinx will not rebuild files that have not been changed, so the original target might not be detected.

Comment: Yes, I ran `make clean`, I still get no warnings.

Comment: Maybe this should be split into two separate questions?